# Should Snakemake workflows using wrappers require cluster nodes to have internet access (e.g. to github)?

Tags: snakemake

When attempting to run some Snakemake workflows that used [wrappers](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/) on one of our clusters, I ran into issues where the jobs would fail with following error:

```
WorkflowError:
Failed to open source file https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/0.77.0/bio/cutadapt/se/environment.yaml
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/0.77.0/bio/cutadapt/se/environment.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x2afb78d6ebe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

The submit node of the cluster is able to get the wrapper scripts, create the conda environments, etc. but the nodes themselves do have access to the internet. Is there a way around this, or should I avoid snakemake wrappers when using clusters with no internet access?

Answer (score 2):

Idk if really a nice solution, but you could clone the wrappers repository and use them as local wrappers?

```
rule index:
    wrapper:
        "file://public/home/bio/index"
```