# Snakemake wrappers not working on SLURM cluster compute nodes without internet

Tags: bioinformatics, slurm, snakemake, hpc

I am trying to use wrappers in my pipeline on a SLURM cluster, where the compute nodes do not have internet access.

I have run the pipeline with `--conda-create-envs-only` first, and then changed the `wrapper:` directives to point to local folders containing `environment.yaml` files.
Jobs fail without specific error. Test rule with the same configuration but without wrappers works. Rules with wrappers work fine on login node if I switch back the `wrapper:` directive to look online.

I am running:

```bash
snakemake --profile myprofile --cores 40 --use-conda
```

Example rule:

```py
# Run FastQC on the fastq.gz files
rule fastqc_fastq_gz:
    input:
        input_dir + "{sample}_{read}_001.fastq.gz",
    output:
        html = output_dir + "fastqc/{sample}_{read}_fastqc.html",
        zip = output_dir + "fastqc/{sample}_{read}_fastqc.zip",
    params: 
        extra = "--quiet",
    log:
        output_dir + "logs/fastqc/{sample}_{read}.log",
    threads: 1,
    resources:
        mem_mb = 1024,   
    wrapper:
        # "file:///path/envs/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/"   # <- Fails on both login and compute nodes
        "v1.31.0/bio/fastqc"                        # <- Works on login node to download env
```

I have also tried using more resources, same behavior.

My profile:

```yaml
cluster:
  mkdir -p logs/{rule} &&
  sbatch
    --partition={resources.partition}
    --qos={resources.qos}
    --cpus-per-task={threads}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --job-name=smk-{rule}-{wildcards}
    --output=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-%j.out
    --error=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-.%j.err
    --account=<account>
    --time={resources.time}
    --parsable
default-resources:
  - partition=<partition>
  - qos=sbatch
  - mem_mb="490G"
  - tmpdir="/path/to/temp/"
  - time="0-10:00:00"
max-jobs-per-second: 10
max-status-checks-per-second: 1
latency-wait: 60
jobs: 16
keep-going: True
rerun-incomplete: True
printshellcmds: True
scheduler: greedy
use-conda: True
cluster-status: status-sacct.sh
```

The submission log reads:

```
Error in rule fastqc_fastq_gz:
    jobid: 38
    input: /path/raw/S9_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz
    output: /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.html, /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.zip
    log: /path/pipeline_out/logs/fastqc/S9_S9_R2.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    conda-env: /path/.snakemake/conda/a116f377bbaddedd93b228a3d4f74b1d_
    cluster_jobid: 1491196

Error executing rule fastqc_fastq_gz on cluster (jobid: 38, external: 1491196, jobscript: /path/.snakemake/tmp.l0raomfw/snakejob.fastqc_fastq_gz.38.sh). For error details see the cluster log and the log files of the involved rule(s).
```

The tmp files do not exist.
Job logs simply read:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 80
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Provided resources: mem_mb=1000, mem_mib=954, disk_mb=7876, disk_mib=7512
Select jobs to execute...

[Date Time]
rule fastqc_fastq_gz:
    input: /path/raw/S9_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz
    output: /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.html, /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.zip
    log: /path/pipeline_out/logs/fastqc/S9_S9_R2.log
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.zip, /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.html
    wildcards: sample=S9_S9, read=R2
    threads: 2
    resources: mem_mb=1000, mem_mib=954, disk_mb=7876, disk_mib=7512, tmpdir=/path/tmp/snakemake, partition=el7taskp, qos=sbatch, time=0-40:00:00

[Date Time]
Error in rule fastqc_fastq_gz:
    jobid: 0
    input: /path/raw/230319/S9_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz
    output: /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.html, /path/pipeline_out/fastqc/S9_S9_R2_fastqc.zip
    log: /path/pipeline_out/logs/fastqc/S9_S9_R2.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    conda-env: /path/.snakemake/conda/a116f377bbaddedd93b228a3d4f74b1d_

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

FastQC logs are empty.

If I run on compute nodes with the `wrapper` directives pointing to github it fails with error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Failed to open source file https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd067df0810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host')), attempt 1/3 failed - retrying in 3 seconds...
Failed to open source file https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd067df2150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host')), attempt 2/3 failed - retrying in 6 seconds...
Failed to open source file https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd067dfc250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host')), attempt 3/3 failed - giving up!
WorkflowError:
Failed to open source file https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd067dfc250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))
  File "/path/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reretry/api.py", line 218, in retry_call
  File "/path/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reretry/api.py", line 31, in __retry_internal
```

Comment: You mention you tested with `wrappers` from the login node. Did you also test with `wrapper: "file:///path/envs/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/"` on the login node, or only with the wrapper pointing to the GitHub repo?

Comment: I did, it does not work. Not sure how to edit post for clarification on this.

Comment: I think it is sufficiently clear now. Since you are not getting any error messages: Could you run the workflow with the wrapper pointing towards GitHub ( `"v1.31.0/bio/fastqc"`)  on a compute node and check / post if you get an error message at least in that case?

Comment: Tried that too, it tries three times to find the wrapper and fails, edited to include this.

Comment: I think I got this to work using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958630/should-snakemake-workflows-using-wrappers-require-cluster-nodes-to-have-internet).  Just a guess, but you have some extra `/` in your path, can you try `file://path/envs/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc`?

Comment: @TroyComi I found the same answer, this is where I got the idea, but it's not working for me. The third `/` is the root. If I remove it I get: `Building DAG of jobs...
WorkflowError:
Failed to open source file path/envs/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/envs/v1.31.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml'`

Comment: Snakemake sometimes has weird bugs and inconsistencies. Some weird ideas you could you try: a) relative path, i.e. `wrapper: "file:envs/v1.31.0./bio/fastqc/environment.yaml"` with the wrapper located relative to the `Snakefile`. b) You could also try a combination of `wrapper: "v1.31.0/bio/fastqc"` combined with a snakemake call with `--wrapper-prefix="file:///path/envs/`. c) Double the backslashes for the path: `wrapper:"file:////path//envs//v1.31.0//bio//fastqc//"` (not everywhere in the snakemake code paths are correctly processed).

Comment: @TroyComi I now realized this is a different solution. Just tried it and it seems to work. Maybe in my solution snakemake is looking for the environment where the yaml file is located, but does not produce an error. I thought it would look at the default env directory after it is built. I would like to see a more streamlined way to use wrappers offline though.

Comment: @euronion the solution that Troy suggested actually works. I don't know if I should mark my question as solved, since I would like to do it without cloning anything. But then again, I would also like to not change the path to the wrapper in the first place.

Comment: Given that your problem is different from the problem linked by @TroyComi I'd recommend you add a short answer and mark it as solved so others can find this solution as well! As for streamlining: Why not open a feature request in the [GitHub](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake) repository? Something like `--wrapper-create-envs-only` analogues to `--conda-create-envs-only` for clusters would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I am marking this as solved.
Snakemake requires internet connection for wrappers, even if the environment has been previously built using `--conda-create-envs-only`. My solution does not work because snakemake needs the whole wrapper pointed to and not just the `yaml` file. The solution Troy pointed to works, but a somewhat more elegant solution suggested by euronion would be to move all wrappers in a path ending in `v1.31.0/bio/<tool>` and then use the `--wrapper-prefix="file:///path/envs/` flag when calling snakemake on the compute nodes. In any case I am opening [a feature request on Github](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2262) for a more streamlined way to do this because even the prefix solution feels clunky and requires the added step of cloning the `snakemake-wrappers` repo.